# Static block not showing up in CMS page

Tags: magento, static-block

I just started working on magento/admin. I am trying to show my static block in one of my CMS pages, but it is not working. I tried to find out answer in google and stack exchange but no luck! Can anyone please help.Thanks.

Below are details: 
This is my static block

[image]

This is my CMS page: I am able to see the text "Yes!" though.

[image]

[image]

Final output: That blue box is my CSS. (jfyi).

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity -  Yes, first I tried over there.But I don't have enough  rep to insert more than one image. That's why I posted question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the latest Magento version 1.9.2.2 that includes the latest patches, then you need to add first the block to Magento white list in teh backend: **System->Permissions->Block**.

See this article: http://www.dudesquare.nl/blog/2015/10/31/static-block-shortcodes-not-working-1-9-2-2/

Comment: Thanks it is working now.I am using Mage v 1.9.2.2 and need to add "CMS/BLOCK" to permissions. :)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Please set different identifier in static block than CMS page. I think CMS page and block identifier same so may be block not display on CMS page.

Also select all store views in static block may be your store is wrong.

And finally remove all cache and refresh all index.

Comment: I retried after doing changes as you suggested. Still the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Please check following:

- Whether you had editor enabled, while calling static block. If yes, please click on Show/Hide Editor button and check what code is there in text area while editor mode off.
- If above does not work, then go to System >> Configuration >> Advanced (Developer) and under Log Settings, Enable Logs. Then refresh cms page in frontend.

I hope this will help you resolve your issue. Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: This is the code is see in editor.
<div class="doubles">Yes!
<p>{{block type="cms/block" block_id="doubles_details"}}</p>
</div>

I tried as mentioned in second point, result is same.

Comment: Have you tried my second suggestion, i.e. enable logs and refresh page then check var >> log folder.

Comment: Yes. var >> log folder is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try to add static blocks through Layout Update XML in CMS Pages use something like this code. Add this code in your CMS page design tab.

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="block.name">
        <action method="setBlockId">
            <block_id>block_id</block_id>
        </action>
    </block>

</reference>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution:

Step 1)Go to admin.

Step 2)Open Top menu System->Permissions->Blocks.

Step 3)click "Add New Block".

write your "Block Name" and Is Allowed "Yes".

Note: Block Name is type of your block for example "cms/block"
after Save Block.  

Step 4)Clear cache and refresh front page. Now Block is showing.

Done.
```